# Error in Database connection at aggregator level

Tags: database, oracle, websphere, spring-integration

Getting below error from code deployed on WAS at:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: 
  error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler#0]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
  Could not get JDBC Connection; 
nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException:
  Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 180000
```

Detailed Trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 180000
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:752)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:762)
        at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore.getMessageGroup(JdbcMessageStore.java:431)
        at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:388)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        ... 157 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 180000
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1684)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:686)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:636)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
        ... 165 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 180000
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1729)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3329)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2610)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1500)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1012)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:669)
        ... 168 more
```

Comment: Its connection problem,make sure your db is up and running or your user pass and instance is valid

Comment: Nope. It happens when i post too many requests on server. Db is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your logs with the `com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager`, I'd recommend you to go to WAS support. Looks like your the Connection Pool is very small for your use-case. Especially having your clue:

> It happens when i post too many requests on server.

Comment: I've tried Artem.  I tagged spring-int because i doubt it is caused by aggregator. 
I have aggregators in sequence linking objects coming from different web services into one super object.    

Flow is like a list of customer objects coming from customer service gets aggregated with department objects in a similar way.  
Also, at another level I have account object too which gets aggregated with customer root object.    

Seems to me that aggregator ,when doesn't receive response behaves like this when put under heavy data.   
Any possibilities?

Comment: I can check for the connection pool solution but not sure if it will be robust on even heavier load

Comment: Doesn't matter. As I said: you have not enough connection pool size. Maybe some other service uses the same pool and doesn't free resources like it is done by the `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Correct. But you really should ensure that every `DataSource` 's user frees connections after the usage.

Comment: Ok. Just for my knowledge, how much load would a typical MESSAGE_GROUP take?? If I bombard ~10K messages on n aggregators , can I assume aggregator would handle this load? Also can you guide me on certain tips on how to deal with aggregator message store in a multi node environment in order to avoid failures ?